# Preserving Uppercase in References

Tags: bibtex, cite-package

I am writing a report using `scrbook` document class. I am creating the reference follows

```
@ARTICLE{example,
author = {A Ho, B.C Stuber and D.E Walter},
title = {IEEE Standard Definitions of Terms},
year = "1993",
journal = "IEEE Std. 145-1993",
 }
```

However, when I compile the file the term IEEE appears as `Ieee` and the authors name appears as `B.C.S.A Ho and D.E Walter`. I am using the `cite` package (`\usepackage{cite}`) and making the reference as

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references}  %references.bib contains the bibliography script.
```

I want IEEE to appear as `IEEE` and not `Ieee` and the names to be ordered properly. I would highly appreciate if someone tells me how to solve this issue.

Comment: Enclose with double curly braces every information: `title = {{IEEE Standard Definitions of Terms}}` for example.

Comment: The author field should be written as `author = {A. Ho and B. C. Stuber and D. E. Walter},`. Note the use of (i) the keyword `and` to separate authors and (ii) spaces to separate the first and middle initials.

Comment: Thank you Romain and Mico for the suggestions! They worked.

Comment: @RomainPicot - The OP stated that he/she wanted to keep `IEEE` in uppercase; it may be OK to lowercase the remaining words in the `title` field.

Comment: @mico you're right but to late to edit the comment. I only IEEE should stay uppercase it should be `title = {{IEEE} Standard Definitions of Terms}`

Comment: Incidentally, using the `@article` entry type for this piece seems rather ill-advised, as the piece wasn't published in a journal. I would use the catch-all `@misc` entry type instead.